# Can't find GMSPlace

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using GoogleMaps sdk with cocoaPods version 1.13, now after I update for new version 2.0, I can't run my project. Looked at my pod files, there are not GMSPlace.h file. How can I find this file, where it located. I think it can't be removed, it's one of base framework classes.

Comment: What is the complete error message that you receive?

Comment: @KENdi Message: Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlace'

Comment: Check this [related issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10217) if it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Now in v2.1 you should also import GooglePlaces.

Using pod:
`pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2.1'`

As described here:
https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2